# How to plot ARACNe plot as a dendrogram in R

Tags: r, plot

I tried running ARACNe and got an output like this -

```
from      to         MI   pvalue
geneA   geneC   0.25         0.1
geneC   geneB   0.28         0.2
geneB   geneA     0.2       0.11
```

And I want to plot a dendrogram plot like this
Dendplot here - https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/09/customer-segmentation-part-3-network-visualization/

How should I use the p value or MI here to see which genes in "from" control the genes in "to".

Comment: Not sure if this question is a good fit for SO in its current form; *"How should I use the p value or MI here to see which genes in "from" control the genes in "to"."* I don't know what MI stands for, and it seems that the question is really about what to use as edge weights in your gene network. This depends on many things, first and foremost domain and experiment-specific knowledge which only you have. Perhaps this question is a better fit for Bioinformatics.SE or SeqAnswers or Biostar?

Answer (score 0):

As Maurits Evers points out in the comments - there's probably a lot of domain knowledge that should be applied to the question of what the right way to visualize and interpret this data is...

But to the question of *how*:

A dendrogram is a representation of pairwise distances between nodes in the tree. It requires a distance matrix that is then passed to a hierarchical clustering function. There are many options for the distance metric and clustering algorithms, and there's a lot of nuance in how to select the correct one for your application. However here's a relatively straightforward way to use the `MI` scores you shared in your example as a similarity metric and turn that into a dendrogram.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(from = c("geneA", "geneC", "geneB"), to = c("geneC", "geneB", "geneA"), MI = c(0.25, 0.28, 0.2), pvalue = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

bind_rows(d, 
          d %>% select(from = to, to = from, everything())) %>% 
  select(from, to, MI) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = to, values_from = MI) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 1))) %>% 
  select(sort(colnames(.))) %>% 
  arrange(from) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("from") %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  (\(x) 1-x) %>% 
  as.dist() %>% 
  hclust() %>% 
  as.dendrogram() %>% 
  plot(ylab = "1 - Mutual Information", main = "Dendrogram based on MI")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>